# Deploy Shiny app with Flexdashboard

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, rstudio-server, flexdashboard, shinyproxy

I know how to deploy a shiny app using http://www.shinyproxy.io/. Basically I just need server.R and ui.R. Then using docker it's a pretty easy job.

However, when using flexdashboard, I only have the .rmd file. How can I implement this deploy now?

Answer (score 9):

This is actually supported **out of the box** by ShinyProxy. You just need to add `yourfile.Rmd` file in the docker image (i.e. add the relevant commands in your Dockerfile), and then use
the

`docker-cmd: ["R", "-e rmarkdown::run('/path/to/yourFile.Rmd')"]`

in the relevant field of the `apps` block. Full details on app configuration [here](http://www.shinyproxy.io/configuration/#apps)

Answer (score 2):

Rendering Shiny R Markdown documents requires server-side support. This is a feature of the open source Shiny Server product (see the [Shiny Server documentation](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/)) which doesn't appear to have been implemented by ShinyProxy.

If you wanted to add support to ShinyProxy it wouldn't be terribly difficult; there are a few details to work out but essentially the proxy just needs to use `rmarkdown::run()` instead of `shiny::runApp()`.

Comment: #jonathan could you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852523/r-flexdashboard-site-not-found-after-deploying

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look here how to make a Docker image with a R Flexdashboard. You then have to change the container cmd in the application.yml of Shinyproxy to `["R", "-e", "rmarkdown::run('/...."]` for rendering the Rmd Flexdashboard file. Please see my blog post at:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-a-shiny-flexdashboard-with-docker-cca338a10d12