# Put a box whithin two rows

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a shinydashboard app, and I want to get one box within two rows (see image below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o11LX.jpg

I tried to mix column and rows, but i didn't manage du get this result.

Here is my ui test :

```
fluidRow(
                box(
                  width = 3,
                  title = "Analyses",
                  dataTableOutput("ind_ana") %>% withSpinner(type = getOption("spinner.type", default = 6))
                ),
                box(
                  width = 3,
                  title = "Limites de quantification",
                  dataTableOutput("ind_lq") %>% withSpinner(type = getOption("spinner.type", default = 6))
                ),
                box(width = 3,
                    title = "Valeurs de références",
                    dataTableOutput("tabFnade")
                    ),
                box(width = 3,
                    title = "Seuils",
                    splitLayout(
                      numericInput("seuil1", NULL, value = 0, min = 0, max =0),
                      colourInput("col1", NULL, "blue")
                    ),
                    splitLayout(
                      numericInput("seuil2", NULL, value = 0, min = 0, max =0),
                      colourInput("col2", NULL, "green")
                    ),
                    splitLayout(
                      numericInput("seuil3", NULL, value = 0, min = 0, max =0),
                      colourInput("col3", NULL, "yellow")
                    ),
                    splitLayout(
                      numericInput("seuil4", NULL, value = 0, min = 0, max =0),
                      colourInput("col4", NULL, "orange")
                    ),
                    splitLayout(
                      numericInput("seuil5", NULL, value = 0, min = 0, max =0),
                      colourInput("col5", NULL, "red")
                    ),
                    splitLayout(
                      numericInput("seuil6", NULL, value = 0, min = 0, max =0),
                      colourInput("col6", NULL, "brown")
                    )
                    )
```

Can I make this with shinydashboard, maybe with css ?

Comment: Have you looked into `flexdashboards` at all? Setting up a basic layout is quite simple: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/layouts.html

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, but I need to build it with shiny or shinydashboard

Comment: It can use shiny! https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html :)

Comment: Looks good ! I will check this. It is also supported by Shiny Server ?

Comment: As far as I know - I typically use docker. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870562/deploy-shiny-app-with-flexdashboard

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it with shiny dashboard using two big box slided into 3 columns :

```
fluidRow(
    column(width = 9,
           box(
             title = "Tab1", width = NULL, height = "200px",
             column(width = 4, "Tab1"),
             column(width = 4, "Tab2"),
             column(width = 4, "Tab3")
           ),
           box(
             title = "Tab4", width = NULL, height = "200px"
           )
    ),
    column(width = 3,
           box(
             title = "Tab5", width = NULL, height = "400px"
           )
    )
  )
```