# How can I make a dockerized Shiny app in a flexdashboard wrapper with golem?

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile, flexdashboard

Is it possible to make a shiny app with flexdashboard as a package with the Open Analytics golem package?
Is it possible to dockerize it afterwards?
How is the workflow going from the flexdashboard .Rmd file?

My Dockerfile so far

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:latest 

MAINTAINER Tim M.Schendzielorz "tim.schendzielorz@googlemail.com"

# Install dependencies 

RUN  echo 'install.packages(c("dplyr","dbplyr","DBI","DT","plotly","flexdashboard","lubridate"), \
        repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org", \
        dependencies=TRUE)' > /tmp/packages.R \
        && Rscript /tmp/packages.R


# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /usr/bin/shiny-server.conf
COPY shiny-server.sh  /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

COPY flexdashboard.Rmd /usr/bin/flexdashboard.Rmd   

# make all app files readable (solves issue when dev in Windows, but building in Ubuntu)
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/bin

# Add shiny user
RUN groupadd  user \
&& useradd --gid user --shell /bin/bash --create-home user

EXPOSE 3838



CMD ["R", "-e rmarkdown::run('/usr/bin/flexdashboard.Rmd')"]
```

I am new to Docker and it seems I need to add the Command to rmarkdown::run in the apps specs as mentioned here: [Deploy Shiny app with Flexdashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870562/deploy-shiny-app-with-flexdashboard)  and start the shiny server with the standard shell command instead? 
Thank you Vincent for docktorrent, will try it now!

Comment: As it is, the question is not a good fit for the StackOverflow format, and is likely to get closed. (Too open, multiple questions, no report of previous attempts, no reproducible code). Though you may have better luck on a forum such as community.rstudio.com that would allow such a discussion to take place. Note: `golem` is primarily made by ThinkR, while Open Analytics makes ShinyProxy

Comment: Hi, have a look to this article (use auto translate form English) and tweak the run function to use rmardown::run(). I will put something on github in the few days with an example.https://thinkr.fr/dockeriser-application-shiny/

Comment: I add an example here : https://github.com/VincentGuyader/docktorrent , this is for `runtime: shiny_prerendered` but you can adapt the functions

Comment: Update 2020-29-01: I ended up deploying the Flexdashboard via Docker and Shinyproxy without golem, but will have a try on my next project. You can check out the Dockerfile I used here: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-a-shiny-flexdashboard-with-docker-cca338a10d12

Answer (score 4):

Just a side note, `{golem}` is not an Open Analytics package.

To answer the "Can we deploy flexdashboard with golem", yes:

The best way to achieve what you intend to do is to put your Rmd inside `inst/`, and modify `run_app` that way:

```r
run_app <- function(...) {
  rmarkdown::run(
    system.file("md.Rmd", package = "mypackage")
  )
}
```

Note that for Docker you'll have to add `library(mypackage)` at the top of the Rmd if you need functions from inside `mypackage`.

That way, you can use the mypackage::run_app() function as a CMD for your Docker file.

Also, note that `{golem}` comes with a `add_dockerfile()` function that will bundle everything you need to install the app. But this won't bundle shiny server inside it.

See: https://rtask.thinkr.fr/shinyapp-runapp-shinyappdir-difference/, especially the part called RSTUDIO PRODUCTS 2/2: SETTING A SHINY SERVER FOR TESTING for an example of a Dockerfile setting a golem app + a shiny server.

Colin